# DataTable RowChanged how to get previous Row value?

Tags: c#, .net, events, datatable

I have a DataTable. When change in row happens I need to get this row and it's previous value(DataRow). How can I get it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should subscribe to the [`ColumnChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.columnchanged.aspx) event, that way you can see the previous and current values.

Example:

```
//code to wire up the handler
custTable.ColumnChanged += new DataColumnChangeEventHandler(Column_Changed);

//code for the event
private static void Column_Changed(object sender, DataColumnChangeEventArgs e )
{
    Console.WriteLine("Column_Changed Event: name={0}; Column={1}; original name={2}", 
        e.Row["name"], e.Column.ColumnName, e.Row["name", DataRowVersion.Original]);
}
```